# Batch - How to write text to multiple files

Tags: batch-file, text, cmd, filepath

Is there anyway to write text to multiple files? I am working on a project where I need to write a specific number to the person's desktop, and one to a flash drive which will save and index the numbers based on the person's username.

What I want to do:

```
echo %random%>>"C:\users\%username%\desktop\num.txt" "D:\Numbers\%username%.txt"
```

Comment: It is not possible to redirect data into multiple files...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just read the file on the desktop, assign a variable to the number and echo it into another file.

echo %random%>>"C:\users\%username%\desktop\number.txt"

FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (C:\users\%username%\desktop\number.txt) DO set number=%%x

echo %number%>>D:\Numbers\%username%.txt

Comment: What? And because I need another 10 characters... what?

Answer (score 0):

This works!

```
echo %random%| cmd /V:ON /C set /P "line=" ^& echo !line!^>^> "C:\users\%username%\desktop\num.txt" ^& echo !line!^>^> "D:\Numbers\%username%.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

just implement a (very simple) routine for that:

```
REM define "command":
set "log=call :log"

%log% hello world!
%log% I have %random% apples.

goto :eof

:log
REM writes the same line to screen and two files
>con: echo(%*
>>"C:\users\%username%\desktop\num.txt" echo(%*
>>"D:\Numbers\%username%.txt" echo(%*
```